# Why mCustomScrollbar does not work correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, mcustomscrollbar

I'm using a plugin for scrolling a content that have an option "moveDragger":

```
function customScrollBar() {
if($(".dropdown .close_list").length) {
    $(".dropdown .close_list").mCustomScrollbar({
        scrollInertia: 300
    });
}
if ($(".compare_table .table_responsive").length != "") {
    $(".compare_table .table_responsive").mCustomScrollbar({
        axis: "x",


        //contentTouchScroll: false,
        documentTouchScroll: false,
        moveDragger:true,


        advanced: {autoExpandHorizontalScroll: true},
        scrollInertia: 300,
    });
  }
}
```

As the documentation says http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/#get-started-section this option allows to scroll content only with the help of a dragger, but in my case I'm able to scroll content by touching content itself (and swiping content if I use a mobile).
How to make it scroll content only by using a horizontal dragger?

test.bikstart.ru/arktika/compare.html